# Draggable and DragTarget: How do I drag a widget and rebuild it inside the DragTarget?

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable

I'm new to flutter and I still don't seem to understand how the UI building works.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DragDemoView extends StatefulWidget
{
  DragDemoView(Key key) : super(key: key);

  @override
  DragDemoViewState createState() => new DragDemoViewState();
}

class DragDemoViewState extends State<DragDemoView>
{

  Icon icon1;
  Icon icon2;
  Icon icon4;
  Icon icon3;

  @override
  void initState() {
    icon1 = new Icon(Icons.wifi, color: Colors.white,);
    icon2 = new Icon(Icons.map, color: Colors.white,);
    icon3 = new Icon(Icons.access_alarm, color: Colors.white,);
    icon4 = new Icon(Icons.account_balance, color: Colors.white,);
    super.initState();
  }

  bool accepted = false;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Draggable(
                child: icon1,
                feedback: icon1,
                childWhenDragging: icon1,
                data: icon1,
              ),
              Draggable(
                child: icon2,
                feedback: icon2,
                childWhenDragging: icon2,
                data: icon2,
              ),
              Draggable(
                child: icon3,
                feedback: icon3,
                childWhenDragging: icon3,
                data: icon3,
              ),
              Draggable(
                child: icon4,
                feedback: icon4,
                childWhenDragging: icon4,
                data: icon4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(),
                  color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent
                ),
                child: DragTarget<Icon>(builder: (context, List<Icon> candidateData, rejectedData) {
                  return accepted ? candidateData.first : new Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.white,);
                },

                  onWillAccept: (data) {
                    return true;
                  },

                  onAccept: (data) {
                    setState(() {
                      accepted = true;
                    });
                  },

                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to move an Icon as a Draggable to a DragTarget and rebuild it there by using the data that I provide with the Draggable. But the result that I get is an error message stating: "Bad state: No element".

The bigger picture here is this: A grid or some kind of layout on the screen, where the user can generate different widgets (An image for example) by drag&dropping them from a list to the desired position. How would i got about that? Provide each Draggable with a key and then build the desired widget inside the DragTarget by looking up the corresponding widget to the key? Or am I going about this completely wrong?